# How do I pass props to ListHeaderComponent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

so I'm navigating to FooItems page from my first component and I'm passing props to navigation.

```
    showFooItemsPage = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('FooItemsComponent', {
            fooItems: this.props.fooItems});
  };
```

On my FooItemsComponents, I have a Flatlist with renderItems function and that is working. However, I want to make changes to the Flatlist items list, then I want to click on Save in my header of my Flatlist component.

The main issue I'm having right now is sending props to the Header Component of my Flatlist. Props is undefined and I have no idea how to send it props from my FooItemsComponent or when I'm navigating between pages?

Here's some snippets from my FooItemsComponent:

```
class Header extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    async componentDidMount() {
       //call some reducer action 
      }

    save = items => {
        this.props.saveItems(items);
        this.props.navigation.navigate("previousComponent");
    }

    render() {
        const {navigation, loading } = this.props;

        return (
        <View>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.save}>
                    <Text style={styles.saveText}>Save</Text> 
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            <View
                style={{
                borderTopWidth: 1,
                borderTopColor: Colors.grey,
                height: 1,
                }}> 
            </View>
        </View>
        );
    }
}

export class FooItemsComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        //some reducer action 
      }

    renderItem = item => {
         if (item.load) {
          return <ActivityIndicator color={Colors.activityColor} size="small" />;
        } else {

          return (
              <View>
                <FooItems
                    {...item}
                    navigation={this.props.navigation}
                    showParticularItems={true}
                />
                </View>
          ); }
      };

    render() {
        const { fooItems, navigation, loading, props} = this.props;
        if (!fooItems) fooItems = [];

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => `key-${index}`}
                data={fooItems}
                renderItem={item => this.renderItem(fooItems.item)}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={Separator}
                ListHeaderComponent={Header}
                ListFooterComponent={loading ? LoadingFooter : Separator}
                />
          </View>

        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass your component as a React element:

```
 <FlatList
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => `key-${index}`}
    data={fooItems}
    renderItem={item => this.renderItem(fooItems.item)}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={Separator}
    ListHeaderComponent={<Header yourProps={'blabla title'}/>}
    ListFooterComponent={loading ? LoadingFooter : Separator}
   />
```

and in `Header` component use `this.props.yourProps`

Comment: You should actually never ever do this. If you do do this, React won't know that the `<Header>` you're rendering is supposed to be the same component between each rerenders. It will therefor create a new header component on each render, which will lead to a performance loss AND will break any state associated by that component. For example, try doing this and passing a `<TextInput>` as your header component. It will lose focus every time you type a character because it's a new text input each time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60622941/searchbar-in-flatlist-loses-focus-after-typing

Comment: I'm agree and i edit this (remove anonymous function)

Answer (score 1):

Never use arrow functions to render components passed as props, React won't have a stable reference to the function and therefor will not know that the header component is supposed to be the same component between renders. It can cause bugs and will hurt performance. See [SearchBar in FlatList loses focus after typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60622941/searchbar-in-flatlist-loses-focus-after-typing) for an example of a bug it can cause. Although, Idan was pretty close to having the correct solution. Instead, do this:

```js
 <FlatList
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => `key-${index}`}
    data={fooItems}
    renderItem={item => this.renderItem(fooItems.item)}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={Separator}
    ListHeaderComponent={<Header yourProps={'blabla title'}/> }
    ListFooterComponent={loading ? LoadingFooter : Separator}
   />
```