# SearchBar in FlatList loses focus after typing

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using a `SearchBar` component in a `FlastList` through the `ListHeaderComponent` prop and filtering the list of items based on the search value. The problem is that after typing one character the search bar loses focus (keyboard is removed) - it's almost like the component re-renders? What am I missing here?

I'm using Android and the problem does not occur if I move the `SearchBar` outside of the `FlatList`.

```
import React from 'react'
import {FlatList, View} from 'react-native'
import { ListItem, SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements'

export const Component = (props) => {
  const [search, setSearch] = React.useState('');
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, name: 'One Thousand' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Two Hundred' },
  ]);

  const filterItems = (items, filter) => {
    return items.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()))
  }

  const renderHeader = () => (
    <SearchBar
      placeholder='Search...'
      onChangeText={setSearch}
      value={search}
    />
  );

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <ListItem
      title={item.name}
      bottomDivider
      chevron
    />
  );

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={filterItems(items, search)}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
      stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Try using `useCallback` or `useMemo` on your `renderHeader` function,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To solve this problem easily, just try not to render the ListHeaderComponent using a separate component, instead use render directly

```
   <FlatList
      ...
      ListHeaderComponent={
        <Searchbar
          placeholder="Search"
          onChangeText={query => {
            setSearch(query);
          }}
          value={search}
        />
      }
    />
```

Comment: This is an extremely important thing to understand fundamentally with react: If a functional component doesn't have a stable reference (like passing an arrow function as a prop), then React wont be able to recognize that it's supposed to be the same component between renders. It will therefor create a new component each time, which will throw away any state that component has and also is expensive computationally.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard is disappearing because the component is re-rendering again and because it is a functional component, the `<SearchBar/>` is re-rendering again. To solve this problem change your component to a class-based component or try separating the `<SearchBar/>` from this component to the parent component.

Comment: Could you explain why a functional component makes the `SearchBar` re-render?

Comment: When the `setSearch` method invokes, it'll trigger the re-rendering of the whole function because you are using hooks(useState).